# How to define Serial Numbers (Editions) in ERC1155?

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin, erc-1155

If I want to mint 2000 tokens of a particular type/id (say 212121) by invoking the [`_mint`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155#ERC1155-_mint-address-uint256-uint256-bytes-) function of ERC1155, how to assign these 2000 tokens a serial number from #1 to #2000 so that I can transfer #60 and the receiver knows that they have received #60 edition of 212121?

My goal is to achieve something like this: [Rare #69/809](https://nbatopshot.com/moment/QC112+ec7e7b63-ad11-4fdf-ad48-c2bfe649a51a)